# Do Hindu scriptures give advice on how to stay present or mindful as one goes about doing regular day to day activities?

Tags: scripture, practice

In addition to formally sitting down and doing mediation, do Hindu scriptures give some advice on how or whether one should stay mindful or present as one goes about doing regular day to day activities?

Comment: Everything is answered in the Gita.

Comment: Very good Qn! Several scriptures & Guru-s advise about having concentration to develop presence of mind. To develop concentration, it's advised to do meditation. To do meditation, it's advised to relax with positivism. To be able to relax, one has to have focus on that. But to be able to focus, one has to have presence of mind. It's probably a circle. :-)

Comment: Good question.  Perhaps, Karma Yoga answers this question @Sanjeev

Answer (score 2):

The following are the excerpts from the teachings of Sri Ramana Maharshi.

> Once ‘A’ asked: How can one be worshipful while engaged in daily work?
>
> Sri Bhagavan did not reply. Ten minutes passed. A few girls came for
>   darsan of Sri Bhagavan. They began to sing and dance. Their song was
>   to the effect: “We will churn the milk without losing thought of
>   Krishna.”
>
> Sri Bhagavan turned to the Swami and said that there was the reply to
>   his question.
>
> This state is called Bhakti, Yoga and Karma.